# Should downvoters be forced to give a reason?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

Often people downvote what seems like perfectly legitimate questions or answers. Comments asking for the reason for downvote are often ignored.

Should it be mandatory for a downvoter to supply a reason? It would at least let the others aware of the downvoter's viewpoint, and open up new lines of discussion.

Comment: -1 asdfasdfasdf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has been done to death on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes).

The consensus is that while it would nice if people did, there's not a lot we can do to enforce this.

Comment: @Chisf - when you say, "...there's not a lot we can do to enforce this." I am confused.  I think you mean that the choice was not to enforce this.  So many times I hear of the 'democratic' nature of these sites, but if the consensus is that it should be required then why isn't it?

Comment: @dbasnett Votes are completely anonymous for privacy reasons. There's no way to track who down-voted but didn't leave a comment.

Comment: @dbasnett - also any scheme to try to force users to leave comments has too many drawbacks to make it worth while.

Comment: @mark - Why is it a big secret?

Comment: @ChrisF - What drawbacks?  Maintaining anonymity?

Comment: @dbasnett We *want* people to vote on the merits of a question or answer without fear that someone is going to enact reprisal on them for misinterpreting a vote. Keeping it anonymous takes the politics out of a key metric and value to the SE network.

Comment: @dbasnett - people leaving rubbish "adkasdjaksjd" type comments or even just as unhelpfully "this question is rubbish" (or similar). Check out the answers, comments and linked questions on my MSO question I linked to.

Comment: @Mark - and without a comment how do we know that the vote had merit?  I know Jeff drew an analogy between these sites and a playground, but I'd like to believe that most people here are adult enough to entertain criticism without seeking retribution.  I try not to say anything about anyone that I wouldn't say to their face.

Comment: @ChrisF  -  and if you allowed down votes on comments that wouldn't happen.

Comment: @dbasnett - see https://twitter.com/#!/lizardbill/status/93074064654073856

Comment: @ChrisF - and if you allowed down votes on comments that wouldn't happen here.

Comment: @dbasnett - then down-votes on comments would have to penalise the commenter in some way and up-votes would have to reward them to compensate. Not something I can see Jeff agreeing to.

Comment: I just don't understand how the score is kept.  So are you saying that upvotes in comments aren't scored?  I did not know that.  It took me years to understand the finer points of scoring in golf.

Comment: @dbasnett - the votes are kept, but they don't confer reputation. Anyway, we've just hit the "move this discussion to chat" limit, so probably now's a good time to stop.

Answer (score 2):

There is **an AJAX `<div>` reminder for users under 2000 rep on each downvote**:

> Please consider adding a comment if you think this post can be improved.

After the first downvote, we can't say we didn't remind them, and honestly that's as good as it gets. Forcing a comment will end in even worse results.

Comment: "Forcing a comment will end in even worse results."  Is this a fact or opinion?  Most, because you are the 'Jeff', will assume fact.  Old guys from Missouri need more.